# Add styles to all nested elements using Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have this markup:

```
<p class='[&_a]:text-[red]'><a>hi</a> world</p>
```

This code adds styles to all `a` tags within `p` tag, but i want to add the class to all elements regardless of the fact that it is `a`, 'div`,or anything else. I tried to do this:

```
<p class='[&_*]:text-[red]'><a>hi</a> world</p>
```

but it does not work.

How can I achieve what I described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"world" is not a child element. If you want to color it, you should use this class :

`class="text-[red] [&_*]:text-[red]"`

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510794/disable-css-focus-on-a-side-tailwindcss

Comment: any explanation please?

Comment: @Shivam the [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) `[&_*]` selects all elements within the element where you’ve added the class. In this case, the only child element is `<a>hi</a>`. That's why "world" is not colored.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to style all children of your `<p>` element.
CSS styles are inherited by all children elements by default.
You can use `text-red` class directly on your `<p>` element without any variant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks me later!

```
[&>*]:text-gray-800
```