# Disable css focus on a side TailwindCss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

On my input component, using Tailwind css, i added this classes:

```
focus:ring focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring
```

These classes are responsible to add styles when the input is focused. Ex: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

**Question**: I want to disable the focus style on the left side when the input will be focused, is this possible in tailwind css?

Comment: I don’t think you can do that with ring, which is based on boxshadow. Maybe you can achieve what you want using border?

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid it's not possible (see https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/3421).

But as suggested by [@Gabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17438890/gabe), you could try to use `border` instead :

```
focus:border-4 focus:border-solid focus:border-l-transparent
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ring](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/ring-width) utility is simple CSS shadow so you may play with it. The closest thing will be to add offset on the X-axis same size as shadow size - however this will add extra shadow on the right

You may rewrite Tailwind CSS variables however I found this unefficient

```html
<button class="focus:ring focus:[--tw-ring-shadow:var(--tw-ring-inset)_3px_0_0_calc(3px_+_var(--tw-ring-offset-width))_var(--tw-ring-color)]"></button>
```

So instead you may create new utility

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .ringed {
    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 3px var(--tw-ring-color);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="focus:ringed"></button>
```

To change ring color use `ring-{color}` utility

I've created a demo with some use cases to show it is not perfect (extra space on right. But it may be OK(?) for a small shadow)

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hj2cPIKC0B)